# Missing minyan on yahrtzeit l'chatchila

Tags: kaddish, minyan, yahrtzeit

Is it mutar (l'chatchila, not shaas hadechak) to not go to minyan on yahrtzeit, and have someone say kaddish on your behalf? (Not to be lazy, but a valuable opportunity presents itself that would not allow you to make minyan?)

Thanks!

Comment: How could it be mutar l'chatchila to miss minyan ever??

Comment: To somewhat build on what @DoubleAA said, even within your question, you're mentioning that it's both "l'chatchila, not shaas hadechak" and "Not to be lazy, but a valuable opportunity presents itself that would not allow you to make minyan". Isn't that already not a "l'chatchila" scenario?

Comment: In effect what @Salmonius is saying is that "lechatchila" is not exactly the same as "intentionally". You're intentionally missing the minyan by deciding not attend it before it even started. But, if the other opportunity is a good reason for you to miss it, it doesn't become "lechatchilla" on anything, b/c that opportunity allows you a way out. "shaas hadechak" means "an urgent moment" - whether it is something you didn't expect came up, or it is an urgent moment because, as MAY be in your case, this opportunity itself is urgent, and you can't miss doing the other action.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28935

Comment: b'seder. so the question is is really if it's any worse to miss minyan on yahrtzeit and have someone say kaddish for you, than to miss it any other day.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mutar to miss a minyan lechatchila. However, if there is such a circumstance (such as being in a city with no minyan) then one can arrange for someone else to say kaddish.

Another reason for this to occur is to be in a minyan in which only one person says kaddish (rather than a group) and the individual involved cannot get a kaddish opportunity.

As an example, see the answers at [Saying Kadish for someone else](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11803/saying-kadish-for-someone-else) or the article at [Pay to Pray](http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/73355/pay-to-pray)